# CoordinatorLayout crashes app with IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm getting a crash (from Crashlytics, unable to reproduce locally) in my app from the `onLayout` function in the `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(SourceFile:848)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15237)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15237)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15237)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15237)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15237)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15237)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4864)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2323)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2029)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:816)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:619)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:588)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:802)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Since I haven't been able to reproduce this myself and have 6 activities with CoordinatorLayouts, how can I go about debugging this?

**Edit**: looks like it will be fixed in the [next support library release](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220762)

Comment: it's not related to CoordinatorLayouts. it's ArrayList outOfBoundException.

Comment: @Amir yes but the CoordinatorLayout is what is causing the exception to occur

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: put some part of your log which written 'Cause by...'

Comment: @Amir unfortunately that's the whole thing - there is no "caused by" exception

Comment: I too have this issue, just started after I upgraded to API 24 tools and libs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and downgrading to a older Android Support Library version(v24.1.1) worked for me. It's seems to be a problem in the Library, you can check the problem out the Android Issue Tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220762).

**UPDATE 1** : Seems like it's going to be resolved in de next version of the Android Support Library(v24.2.1), thanks [Daniel Rampelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4942782/daniel-rampelt) for the update

**UPDATE 2** : 24.2.1 is out as of today and the error seems to be resolved—at least I couldnae reproduce it with the current version. – PattaFeuFeu

**UPDATE 3** :  24.2.1 introduced new bug: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536519/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-rect-should-intersect-with-childs-bounds) – AAverin

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is also fixed for the next release as well.

Comment: 24.2.1 is out as of today and the error seems to be resolved—at least I couldnae reproduce it with the current version.

Comment: 24.2.1 introduced new bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536519/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-rect-should-intersect-with-childs-bounds

Answer (score 0):

Even i had the same issue

my issue was because of showing snackbar 
i enclosed showing snackbar code with try catch now its workng fine

```
 /**
 * try catch becuase of SupportLibrary bug link "https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220762"
 *
 * @param v
 */
public void showConnectionErr(View v) {
    try {
        Snackbar b = getFailureSnackBar(v, "Bluetooth connection lost", false);
        b.setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new ConnectThread().execute();
            }
        });
        b.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```