# Get Gps cordinates and send it with Sms

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a BroadcastReciever which calls sms activity gets Gps cordinates and sends it to another device. The problem is that whenever  if I call getGPSLocation the application fails. and if I comment it out it works fine. There is something in location that causes the app to fail but I could not find it. Please can someone helps to to find a problem. Thanks for your attention.

```
public class SMS extends AppCompatActivity {
private String myGPSLocation;
private LocationManager myLocationManager;
boolean issent = false;
String text = "your cordinates ";
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //call message method pass getGPS function which returns string
    myLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            //makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
            myGPSLocation = location.toString();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    message(text + getGPSLocation());
}


private String getGPSLocation() {
    String cords;
    if (myGPSLocation == null) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return "PERMITED";
        }
        Location locationGPS = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        cords = locationGPS.toString();
        return  cords;
    }
    else {
        return myGPSLocation;
    }

}






public void message(String info)
{

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String num = settings.getString("phone_number", "");
    if(num != "") {
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null, info, pi, null);
        issent = true;
        this.finish();
    } else { Toast.makeText(this, "Phone is not SET ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   this.finish();}
    }
boolean isSent()
{
    return issent;
}
```

}

LOGCAT

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rect should intersect with child's bounds.
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.offsetChildByInset(CoordinatorLayout.java:1319)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onChildViewsChanged(CoordinatorLayout.java:1257)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$OnPreDrawListener.onPreDraw(CoordinatorLayout.java:1805)
                      at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:864)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2146)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1253)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6402)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: *application fails* means it crashes? If it crashes please post the logcat of that?

Comment: I added the logcat. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Swap these 2 lines. You are calling getGPSLocation() method before initializing **myLocationManager** which leads to NLP.

```
    message(text + getGPSLocation());
    myLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

to

```
    myLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    message(text + getGPSLocation());
```

You can do one more check 
In

```
private String getGPSLocation() {
    String cords;
    if (myGPSLocation == null) {

      if(myLocationManager != null){

    ....//your code

      }

    }
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error app crashes. it only crashes when I call message(text + getGPSLocation());

Comment: @iliasidamonidze can u post recent logcat?

Comment: It looks like error is caused by                                                                 Location locationGPS = myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            cords = locationGPS.toString();

Comment: No its different issue check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536519/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-rect-should-intersect-with-childs-bounds)

Comment: I have no idea what else can I blame. because every time I comment locationGPS.toString()   the rest of the code works fine......

Comment: @iliasidamonidze is your issue fixed?